# How do you compile python with >1024 file descriptors?

Tags: python, centos, centos5

The workaround for an issue in supervisord is to:
"compile a Python that supports > 1024 file descriptors"

https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/26

Can someone please walk me through what changes are necessary to accomplish this? I have the python 2.7.2 source extracted and ready to go.

Running centos 5.6, if that matters.

Thanks.

Update: ulimit -n is already set to 65535. This is the full error I'm getting when starting supervisord:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/bin/supervisord", line 8, in 
>       load_entry_point('supervisor==3.0a10', 'console_scripts', 'supervisord')()
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.0a10-py2.7.egg/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 372, in main
>       go(options)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.0a10-py2.7.egg/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 382, in go d.main()
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.0a10-py2.7.egg/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 95, in main
>       self.run()
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.0a10-py2.7.egg/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 112, in run
>       self.runforever()
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.0a10-py2.7.egg/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 230, in runforever
>       r, w, x = self.options.select(r, w, x, timeout)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.0a10-py2.7.egg/supervisor/options.py", line 1113, in select
>       return select.select(r, w, x, timeout) 
>   ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()

Comment: In what way did you run out of descriptors?  If you ran out simply opening files, that's much different from if you ran out when using select(), for example.

Comment: my ulimit -n is already: 65535

Comment: (oops hit enter too early) ... updated the question with the full error

Comment: What do you get if you run python -c "import resource; print resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)"?

Comment: (65535, 65535)      (trying to get to 15char)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's actually the limit of the underlying `select(2)` system call.

From the man page:

```
An fd_set is a fixed size buffer.  Executing FD_CLR() or FD_SET() with a value of fd 
that  is  negative  or  is equal  to  or  larger  than  FD_SETSIZE will result in 
undefined behavior.
```

And the standard FD_SETSIZE is 1024.

```
/usr/include/linux/posix_types.h:#define __FD_SETSIZE   1024
```

So it's not a Python issue. The `poll(2)` and `epoll(2)` system calls have a much larger limit. What you really need to do use use the `select.epoll` object (still in the `select` module) instead of `select.

Comment: You can verify this if you looked at the CPython source.  It ultimately makes a call to the standard C `fopen()` function to open the file.  There are no restrictions imposed by python as far as I could tell.